# What is RealTimeStateMachine ? (Exception in Google Play services)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services

08-23 15:11:25.529     600-7745/com.google.android.gms

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RealTimeStateMachine
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at aps.d(SourceFile:859)
    at aqc.a(SourceFile:1001)
    at aqc.a(SourceFile:833)
    at aqc.a(SourceFile:52)
    at aqf.a(SourceFile:636)
    at afe.a(SourceFile:968)
    at afe.handleMessage(SourceFile:796)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Proguard restore stack not help. Where and what is the exception?

Comment: when googling as exeption there is no result except your question :)

Comment: so you'd better if add some code so that one can follow what is the reason and where to look at